# How to Convert 1.3333333 to 1.34 in db2 and SQL?

Tags: sql, database, db2

How to Convert 1.3333333 to 1.34 in db2 and SQL ?

Comment: you can google it easily...!

Comment: ez googling 2k18

Comment: `(CEILING(1.3333333*100))/100`

Comment: use https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_ceil

Comment: Thanks All for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
SELECT CEIL(1.3333333*100)/100
```

Multiply with hundred then get ceil value and divide it by 100. you will have the answer.

Comment: and how is that different from my comment?

Comment: When I am putting the answer I Didn't see your comment. Both The CEIL() function is a synonym for the CEILING() function. Credit it yours.

Comment: Thanks both of you !

Answer (score 1):

use below function for sql .

```
    SELECT ROUND(1.3333333, 2);
```

Comment: That will give you 1.33

Comment: Will round to 1.33000000

Comment: yes thats true  it will be 1.33 for 1.34 input sud be 1.344444. if upvote it make sence

Comment: Thanks for replying !